# statically link a libtiff tool

Tags: compiling, static-linking, libtiff

I downloaded the latest version of [libtiff](https://gitlab.com/libtiff/libtiff), made some modifications, and now want to produce a statically-linked version of one of the components, `tiffset`. I disabled most of the unneeded libraries and tried using "--disable-shared" to prevent dynamic linking, but the program still fails to run on another computer with a standard issue of libtiff (it loads the installed libraries, whereas it depends on a modified version not available on that system). Is there a simple way to produce a fully statically linked object file, e.g., by passing arguments via LDFLAGS?